# Quando declara uma interface na classe, quem deve implementá-la?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança, interface

```
class Gerente extends Funcionario implements Autenticavel {
```

Ele quis dizer que `Gerente` implementa a interface `Autenticavel`, ou `Funcionario` que irá implementa a interface?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O `Gerente` implementará ali mesmo logo abaixo. A assinatura desta classe tem a interface, então é essa classe que terá que implementar.

Se `Funcionario` já tivesse implementado, mesmo que se faça uma reimplementação em `Gerente`, não precisaria declarar nessa classe, já estaria implicitamente declarado por ela ter herdado de uma classe que já tem a interface.

Não entrei no mérito que essa herança específica parece conceitualmente errada porque não é o foco da pergunta.